# AS3 Attack Animation Issues

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a beat em up game and right now i got my character attacking. I have 3 attack animation so far and works just about. If you keep mashing the attack button it will attack but the problem is it goes to the next attack animation as soon as the attack button is down and I don't want that. How can i make it go to the next attack animation once the current attack animation has finished instead of jumping to the next frame midway of it's current animation. So i want the character to finish its attack and if the player still keys in the attack key it will go to the next attack frame.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Attack variables
        var Attacking:Boolean = false;
        var Punches:int = 0;
        var Punching:Boolean = false;
        var Kicks:int = 0;
        var Kicking:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }

        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);

                //If A key is down
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    Attacking = true;
                    Punching = true;
                    Punches++;
                }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //If player is not attacking
            if (Attacking == false)
            {
                Punching = false;
                Punches = 0;
                Kicking = false;
                Kicks = 0;
            }   
            else if (Attacking == true)
            {

                if (Punching == true)
                {
                    gotoAndStop('Jab' + Punches);
                }
            }

        }


        function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyPressed);

        }
    }
}
```

Also within the last frame of every attack animation i have put down

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();
MovieClip(parent).Attacking = false;
MovieClip(parent).Punches = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove the event listener adding and removing from both `KeyPressed` and `KeyUp` methods (they are not needed and they will just cause problemes) and register the key up event in the costructor just like the other two.

Secondly, to accomplish this you will need to check if the key is down instead of listening for the key press. To do this you will need a new field called, for instance, `holdingAttackKey`.

```
        var holdingAttackKey:Boolean = false;  



        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                holdingAttackKey = true;

                Attacking = true;
                Punching = true;
                //...



    function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        holdingAttackKey = false;
    }



    function Update(event:Event)
    {
        if(holdingAttackKey && Attacking==false) {
                Attacking = true;
                Punching = true;
                Punches++;
        }
        //....
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try but I need those listeners for a different reason/function which works. The code i placed is just the relevant codes out of my entire lengthy code, but i will give this a try and will let you know